# Zend registry mail sender : How to debug?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Mail doesn't get sent properly. I need to help to properly debug as to why it isn't working on the server.  Any solution?

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);

$mailer = Zend_Registry::get('mailer');
if ($to) {
    $mailer->setsendBcc(true);
}
// Add admin emails as recipient.
$to[$config->email->to] = '';
$mailer->setTo($to);        
$mailer->setTokens($mailParams);
$mailer->setTemplate($template);
$result = $mailer->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Registry only stores stuff (eg. objects). We don't know what object is '$mailer'. It's not standard `Zend_Mail` object. You would need to check it - `get_class($mailer)` or look for `Zend_Registry::set('mailer'`.

You can always try:

```
try{
  $result = $mailer->send();
}catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Edit:
Also check if you are setting recipient correctly. It looks a bit odd in your code.